# How do I check if my router or usb wifi is the cause of poor speeds?

Tags: wireless-networking, dd-wrt

I flashed my router with [dd wrt](https://www.dd-wrt.com) firmware. Right now it appears that if I download something I'll get poor speeds while I am transferring data from my pc to my pi. My local speed is 600KB/s to 1MB/s. My download speed (which isn't great here) is typically 1.6MB/s but it appears I can never achieve that speed while I'm transferring. I was wondering if my USB WIFI is the problem?

I tried having my pi and desktop in the same room using a AdHoc network I achieve 3+MB/s (I have a slow SD card so I think that's the bottleneck). When I moved the pi to where it normally is I got 1MBps (how do I write megabytes per second?). So I imagine if all traffic goes through my router I'd have 3MBps - 1.6 (from internet) leaving 1.4 for my transfer but that isn't the case. I'm not sure what my wifi supports but most protocols seem to support 54megabits per second. I don't appear to be getting that. How do I troubleshoot the issue? I can't imagine the issue is distance? Everything is 1 floor apart from the router. The signal strength from the PC is -79dBm

Comment: Start by calculating what your theoretical max speed should be given what your devices are capable of. You really can't reason successfully about Wi-Fi speed without knowing the specs of the Wi-Fi chips in your router(s) and client(s). Also note that downloads and file copies are measured in MebiBytes per second (MiB/sec), but network speeds are measured in megabits per second (mbps). 1 MiB/sec = about 8.4 mbps.

Comment: Also note that -79 dBm RSSI is pretty low. You want better than -60 dBm if you want to get the top data rates your equipment is capable of.